# weird usage of php open and close tag in callback functions

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a piece of TwentyTwelve WordPress theme which actually proposed as a good material for learning theme development by WordPress itself.

This function is sent as a callback. But the thing is the weird usage of PHP open and close tags in the code:

I've marked them with this comment: /* <------ LIKE THIS */

```
function twentytwelve_header_style() {
 $text_color = get_header_textcolor();


 if ( $text_color == get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' ) ) {
    return;
 }

 ?> /* <------ LIKE THIS */
 <style type="text/css" id="twentytwelve-header-css">
 <?php

if ( ! display_header_text() ) :
    ?>
.site-title,
.site-description {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
    <?php

    else :
        ?>
    .site-header h1 a,
    .site-header h2 {
        color: #<?php echo $text_color; ?>;
    }
<?php endif; ?>
</style>
<?php   /* <------ LIKE THIS */
}
```

why are they used in this way?

Comment: yeah weird in some way but primarily its just sandwiching php code with css markup like the code above, this is what some plugins in wordpress do when some settings are saved in PHP and the database, then the conditions are used to render css settings. and fyi you really don't need to follow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a clean code but it's not strange as you think, the php tag are closed when the function print directly html, you can change your code like this:

```
<?php // I think that your code miss opening tag or maybe opening tag is before your snippet

function twentytwelve_header_style() {
 $text_color = get_header_textcolor();


 if ( $text_color == get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' ) ) {
    return;
 }

 echo '<style type="text/css" id="twentytwelve-header-css">'; /* <------ ECHO AND NO CLOSING PHP TAG */

if ( ! display_header_text() ) :

    echo '.site-title, .site-description { position: absolute; clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */ clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); }'; /* <------ ECHO AND NO CLOSING PHP TAG */
    else :
    echo '.site-header h1 a, .site-header h2 { color: #<?php echo $text_color; }'; /* <------ ECHO AND NO CLOSING PHP TAG */
endif;
echo '</style>'; /* <------ ECHO AND NO CLOSING PHP TAG */
```